# XmlSchemaInference class for custom simpletypes

Tags: c#, xsd

Is it possible to use the [XmlSchemaInference class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz2797k1(v=vs.110).aspx) to infer custom simple types?

For example defining a pattern in a simple type and then if a string matches that pattern it's type should instead be that pattern? I suppose a way of extending  the "[Rules for Inferring Simple Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa3k0sts(v=vs.110).aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

The XmlSchemaInference class is fairly basic it can figure out a few base types but that's about it, typically its a good starting point, then you have to get in there are re-factor it a bit.

I've not seen any great inference tools, ultimately its a fairly tricky problem where you are converging on a 'best' solution, and without huge amounts of sample data you can't be sure whether parts of a structure are optional or just not allowed in certain locations.